# How to step in to WPF codes while visual studio debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, debugging, data-binding

I would like to debug in to System.Windows.UIElement.Visibility.set.
But while debugging, got the error as - Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Windows.UIElement.Visibility.set'.
I have confirmed that the PresentationCore.dll pdb(symbol) is loaded from the module window.
Also, ensured this https://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html

Tried with VS2017, .NET framework 4.8.
Please help to step in to WPF codes.

Answer (score 0):

To debug .net framework code, you need to load the symbols.

> Symbols are useful for debugging and other diagnostic tools. The contents of symbol files vary between languages, compilers, and platforms. At a very high level symbols are a mapping between the source code and the binary produced by the compiler. These mappings are used by tools like Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code to resolve source line number information or local variable names.

An excellent guide can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2019

Symbols are not loaded by default for framework or external libraries

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My problem is symbol loaded, but cannot step in to. For the framework calls, the mscorlib.pdb is fine and I can step into. But for the APIs in PresentationCore.pdb cannot step into. The PresentationCore.pdb  loaded correctly.